# venv not respecting --copies argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, vagrant, python-venv, vagrant-windows

I am ssh’d into a development environment (vagrant Ubuntu box) and my project directory is mapped to another filesystem (via vbox) so symlinks are not supported. I am attempting to create a new venv, but the --copies flag isn’t being respected.

```
$sudo python -m venv --copies venv 
Error: [Errno 71] Protocol error: 'lib' -> '/home/vagrant/vagrant_projects/rurp/venv/lib64'
```

If I use python 2.7 ($virtualenv  venv --always-copy) it works, but not with the python3 venv --copies implementation. The --always-copy argument was a workaround for similar issues with python2.x.

I could not find anything online indicating a bug in venv and am at a bit of a loss. Has anyone else had this issue?

```
$ python -V
Python 3.6.9
```

Thank you in advance.

Edit: Also tested in python 3.8.1.

Comment: Looking at the [source code for `venv`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/venv/__init__.py#L420), `--copies` looks like a no-op unless you are using Windows.

Comment: It set a defualt, but shouldn't that be overridden with the [group.add_argument a few lines later](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/venv/__init__.py#L430)?

Comment: `--copies` uses `store_false` as its action, which just stores `False` in the destination, regardless of what is already there, so it's a no-op if the default is already `False`.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think that this qualifies as a bug or just a documentation issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per @chepner's comment above, it looks like the --copies argument is ignored on non-Windows systems (no mention of this in the documentation). I was able to workaround the issue by creating the venv in a local directory, manually copying the symlinked lib64 to a real directory, moving the venv to my project folder and manually updating the activation scripts. Ugly, but it works.

```
$cd ~
$python3 -m venv --copies --clear venv
$cp -r --remove-destination `readlink lib64` lib64
$cp -r venv vagrant_project/rurp/
```

I would be happy to accept a more elegant answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem on a Windows host and an Ubuntu box. No need for ugly workarounds. This [github issue](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2084) has the solution. Set the environment variable:

```
VIRTUALENV_ALWAYS_COPY=1 virtualenv /path/to/env
```

Comment: The `virtualenv` package has a working `--copies` argument; only the built-in `venv` doesn't.